# Extraer dato de un arreglo complejo en Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente arreglo llamado *listas* y quiero acceder a el método de regularidad y al valor dentro de este que tiene regularidad con javascript y este almacenarlo en una variable, pero no he podido realizarlo. El arreglo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede visualizar, se encuentra de ese arreglo llamado *lista* un objeto llamado *regularidad* y dentro de este el valor de regularidad que necesito almacenar dentro de una variable ejemplo que me almacene el número 2 que pertenece a esa llave regularidad. Tengo lo siguiente para ingresar hasta regularidad, pero no puedo extraer el resto, o no sé si lo estoy interpretando de manera errónea:

```js
listas['regularidad'] = <? echo json_encode($regularidad[0]); ?>;
var regularidad = <? echo json_encode($regularidad); ?>;
console.log(regularidad[0]);
```

Comment: 1. Sería bueno que agregues el ejemplo de salida _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. 2. Pista: acceso a propiedades de objeto => con un punto (`.`).

Comment: La imagen es el resultado del `console.log()`?

Comment: @alanfcm si es el resultado del console.log()

Comment: Intenta con `console.log(regularidad[0].regularidad[0].regularidad);`

Comment: En la consola de Chrome, si te pones encima de la propiedad y le das al botón derecho del ratón, tienes la opción de copiar la ruta de la propiedad, luego tan solo tienes que indicar <code>console.log(NombreObjeto.pegaaquilaruta);</code> (Que alguien me explique como se pone el código en los comentarios!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Como estan,

Doy respuesta y agradezco a quienes realizarón sus comentarios, con la respuesta de @alanfcm funciono correctamente:

```
console.log(regularidad[0].regularidad[0].regularidad);
```

pero de igual forma pude encontrar otra forma de acceder a este dato de la siguiente manera:

**

```
var regu = listas["regularidad"].regularidad;
console.log(regu);
```

**

de esta forma ingreso al arreglo de regularidad y al metodo de regularidad para ingresar finalmente al valor que necesito que es regularidad.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración